# Swift - Hiding Tab bar in PageViewContoller scenes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, interface-builder

I set up a series of onboarding scenes for my app using [this tutorial](http://shrikar.com/blog/2015/01/17/ios-swift-tutorial-uipageviewcontroller-as-user-onboarding-tool/), and elsewhere in my app use a TabViewController. When I run the app, the Onboarding scenes have a blank tab bar at the bottom.

I've tried ticking "Hide Bottom Bar on Push" from all 3 views on interface builder:

[image]

I've also tried adding

`self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true` to the `override func viewDidLoad()` functions of the ViewController, PageViewController and PageContentViewController. No joy!

Also tried `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true` in the same places.

[Elsewhere](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/how-would-i-hide-the-tab-bar-in-the-bottom-of-tabbed-application-programmatically-in-swift) I've found references to this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showLogin"{
        println("showLogin seque called")
        let bottomBar = segue.destinationViewController as LoginViewController
        bottomBar.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        bottomBar.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    }
}
```

but, I don't have any named segues, so not sure how to identify the segue.

Any help would be amazing!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To give the Segue name, first choose the segue and then go to Attributes Inspector.
Below there you find Storyboard Segue, from there you provide Identifier name in Identifier Box.

Thanks